# Fetching Image from other post/page with custom type

Tags: page-template, images

I'm building a theme that display image according to a category. Exemple, There a Fashion section, which is a page. On that page I have uploaded photo related to fashion. Another page is Portraits, which display portrait photography and so on. On my home page I would like to display all the recent photo that I have uploaded through the other section/page.

Right now I can only show image related to a specific page or post with this script:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo '<li>';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
           echo '<p>';
           echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
           echo '</p></li>';

          }
     }

 endwhile; endif; ?>
```

How can I extend this script to fetch images/photos in other post/page?

I would like to specified that I'm kind of new in theme developement...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that in many ways ,
but providing that you use a relatively new wordpress, you should use 
the_post_thumbnail().

you define it in functions.php , like so :

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); //thumnails set_post_thumbnail_size( 150,230, true ); // defaultpost thumbnails 
add_image_size( 'your-custom-name-2', 400, 9999 ); // some size thumbnail  
add_image_size( 'your-custom-name-2', 400, 300,false ); // another size 
add_image_size( 'whatEverName', 100, 100, false ); // yet another
```

The "false" or  "true" parameters regard the cropping mode (read more below )
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

and also here

[Display thumbnail from custom field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35518/display-thumbnail-from-custom-field/35550#35550)

you should then define a post default image when you upload an image (you will see it on the upload screen ) - then you can just call it in your theme like so :

`the_post_thumbnail('whatEverName');` //depending on the size you want.

this however , will get you ONE defined image .
It will also get you the IMAGE ITSELF .
if you want the URL, size or something else, you should use

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'whatEverName');
```

If you want multiple images - you can use this :

```
<?php //GET THE FIRST IMAGE
    $args = array(
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => null,
    'numberposts'    => 1, //change if you want another number
    );
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {

            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

            echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail', false, false);
    }
} ?>

// CONTENT AND OTHER STUFF...

<?php //GET ALL EXPECT FIRST IMAGE
    $args = array(
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => null,
    'numberposts'    => -1,
    );
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {
    $no_show=true;
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    if($no_show) {$no_show=false; continue; }
            echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail', false, false);
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Hi, not sure you see exactly what I meant. I probably did not explain it well. You you go see at my site what I mean. http://www.chrisbergeronphoto.com/dummy you will see more what I mean. If you click on Fashion for exemple, you'll see all the images I uploaded in fashion (it's a slideshow). if you click on other link you'll see images that are related to there page. What I want is to show on "Recent work" image that belong to other page! I'm not shure how to achieve this, and the way you showed me I'm not sure it applied to what I want to do.

Comment: well, than just use it outside the loop , or put the categories/pages/categories you want inside the arguments in the same code I posted ..

Comment: Nice site by the way

Comment: Hi again, I'm glad that you like the site! Thanks! I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but the code you have posted work only if I upload images in the page the code reside. (on my theme it's called page-test.php, and it's a template page). All the other page I picked a Feature thumbnail and it's not working. I'm trying to find the argument to call a page instead of a category and find nothing... I don't believe that I'm the only one on the planet who want to do something like that, it most exist a solution.

Comment: All right, I thing I'm getting there... I changed in the `$args`,  `$post->ID` for `$page->ID` and it output all the pictures that have been post in the other pages. Nice, but I still want to control which picture will be shown is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I am a bit baffled as to what you want exactly, but Like I said, your initial code is OK - you just have to use it OUTSIDE the loop. (drop the if/while) . if you want from ALL IMAGES, just set `'post_parent' => NULL'`

Comment: I am a bit baffled as to what you want exactly, but Like I said, your initial code is OK - you just have to use it OUTSIDE the loop. (drop the if/while) . if you want from ALL IMAGES, just set `'post_parent' => NULL'` - if you want to set number of images, use the `'numberposts' => -1,` - to order you can use the order argument, to exclude - use the exclude argument  (or `'post__not_in' => array(3,8),` . if you more want control, you can change their ORDER . that said, If you want only SPECIFIC images, why not do a page with your images on it ?

Comment: Hi, your code does work, I did put it outside the loop and I eventually figure out that using `'post_parent' => NULL'` got every images that is in the media library. What I was hoping is to find a way to show image on a different page, that I had "flagged" while I upload them, then the code can call them and output it on a page automatically. So I don't have to manage the same file twice. Thats why I thought that using custom type might help, but I think I'm wrong on this!

Comment: if you want to "flag" a picture, you could have a special taxonomy for attachments. but it is really an "overkill" for what you need .. As for what I saw , your´s is a portfolio site.. which means it is not updated very frequently . the easiest and most sane way , IMHO, would be to set up a page especially for that , then just insert the images that you want . no plugins, no custom queries, wordpress-out-of-the-box.

Comment: Yeah, I think your right, It might be the simplest way to do this. None the less, I learn a lot just by doing this. Thank you very much for your help it's extremely appreciated.