# Trying to use Advanced Custom Fields with custom image sizes

Tags: plugins, custom-field, thumbnails

I have a product section on my wp-site. I am trying to display the attached thumbnail image in specific sizes that are automatically cropped to the right size.

I have used **Advanced Custom Fields** to create a field called product_thumbnail
I have used **Additional Image Sizes** to create a new image size called products
I have used the following code on another word press site and it worked fine, but on my current site it returns empty.

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('product_thumbnail'), 'products'); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" /></a>
```

I have ran a batch to make sure my images are created if not already.
This is boggling my mind. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

why **OH WHY** does everybody insist on making custom fields for everything .

is there a special reason that you would want the use of custom fields ?
If so, please explain exactly what you want to achieve . 
If not - a much better approach (and more fool-proof for non-computer-savvy-clients) would be to use `the_post_thumbnail();`   -  like you stated in your question already, with Additional image sizes in the theme .

I do not want to duplicate my answers - so you just as well read here :

[Display thumbnail from custom field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35518/display-thumbnail-from-custom-field/35550#35550)

Basically you will use

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="the_post_thumbnail('your_size_name');" /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks. There is no reason to use custom fields besides trying to make it all one area where the user adds info. This was helpful, I just swapped it for the featured image method.

Comment: ACF also allows fields to be marked as required and can really narrow the margin of admin errors for those non-computer-savvy-clients so I'm unclear on @krembo99 's aversion to it.